# How do i read javascript array in c sharp

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have created a function in javascript like a class

```
 function myclass
{
this.Id=null;
this.Name=null;
}
```

from other function i am returning a list(Array in javascript) of myclass

```
function ReturnList
{
   var lst=[];
   var objmyclass=new myclass();
   objmyclass.Id=1;
objmyclass.Name="abc";

var objmyclass1=new myclass();
   objmyclass1.Id=1;
objmyclass1.Name="abc";

lst.push(objmyclass);
lst.push(objmyclass1);

PageMethods.GetListData(lst,onsuccess);

return false;
}
```

How do i read the lst in my webmethod

```
[WebMethod()]
public static bool GetListData(datatype lst)
{
   //How to read each item from lst
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to look at MSDN's ASP .NET JSON article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299886.aspx